# Django advanced join / query, how to filter foreign keys?

Tags: django, join, annotations

I have this two models.

```
class City(models.Model):
    city    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CityTranslation(models.Model):
    city    = models.ForeignKey(City)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lang    = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    prio    = models.IntegerField()
```

Every city can have multiple translated names within one language.

So I want to get all City's with country="Poland". If a corresponding City has one or more CityTranslations with lang=name. I want to get only the first ordered by prio.

I am doing something like that now.

```
City.objects.filter(country="Poland", citytranslation__land="pl").annotate(transname=F("alt_names__name"))
```

But this is not working, because:

1. If there is a City without a CityTranslation it want be listed
2. If there are multiple CityTranslation's they all will be shown. But I just want the first. (... .ordered_by('prio').first())

Any idea?

EDIT:
Solved it by using a @property field, which is ordering my CityTranslation by prio and picks the first one:

```
@propert
def transcity(self):
    return self.citytranslation.filter(lang="pl").order_by('-prio').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def magic(passed_country="Poland", passed_lang="pl")
    # I want to get all City's with country="Poland".
    cities = City.objects.filter(country=passed_country)

    # If a corresponding City has one or more CityTranslations with lang=name. I want to get only the first ordered by prio.
    suitable_cities = cities.filter(citytranslation__lang=passed_lang)
    if suitable_cities.exists()
        first_matching_city = suitable_cities.orderby('prio').first()
    else:
        first_matching_city = cities.orderby('prio').first()

    return first_matching_city
```

May need to set up a relatedname on citytranslation.

May not need orderby if you plan on ordering by ID anyways.